# Phishing alert in Magento admin

Tags: magento

I have a very strange phishing alert in the magento admin of my website. It appear only on the "my account" page, without additionnal information on origin of this problem.

Except this page, the entire website work perfectly, the CMS is up to date (1.7.0.2) and I have no alert in google webmaster tools.

[image: Capture du 2013-07-01 10 47 06 sur Imagesia]
<sub>(source: [imagesia.com](http://img.imagesia.com/fichiers/9h/capture-du-2013-07-01-10-47-06_imagesia-com_9hnc_large.png))</sub>

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it standard magento ? The URL doesn't seem like a magento url ("csconsole/system_account" vs "customer/account") If not you may have some wicked JS or HTML

Comment: Yes @Bixi, it's standard magento. `cscustom` is the custom admin path to avoid bots that brute-force the default admin path.